# Langchain PyPDF can use with another language?

Tags: langchain

I am encountering an issue with reading PDF files in Thai language. When I try to convert the content of these PDFs, the output I receive is in ASCII format, which is not readable and does not represent the Thai text correctly. I would like to find a solution that enables me to convert the content from these Thai language PDFs into readable text. This is important for my work with LangChain, as I need to process and understand the content in these documents. Could you provide guidance or solutions on how to effectively convert or read Thai text from PDFs, especially when the output is currently in ASCII format?

this is my code

```
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader

openai.api_key  = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

llm_name = "gpt-3.5-turbo"
print(llm_name)

loader = PyPDFLoader("data/wilee.pdf")
pages = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 1500,
    chunk_overlap = 150
     )
splits = text_splitter.split_documents(pages)
```

output

```
page_content='51\n\x1c\x0e\x0b\x14\x1aJ\t\x15\x10\x01\x01\r\x14\x01\x1b\t\x0c  \n\x02\r\x03+(\x15\x13\x04. \x17E\x17\x07\x02\x1d\x16\n\x08\t\x1b\t\x0c  \x02+\x16\x10.\x17\x0c\x04\x03O \x12\x15\x1f3\x07\x17\x16  \x01 \t&,(\x15\x13\x04. \x17E\x17\x07\x1c\x0f)\x14\x15\x1f%\x14\x17\x1f\x1c3\x0b
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell why your code isn't working when you haven't posted your code. You may want to take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to better understand how this site works, and then [edit] your post to provide more information.